# Constant reset of full-speed USB device using ehci-pci

Tags: usb, reset

*Running 14.04.3 Ubuntu Desktop on old HP 8510w laptop with USB 2.0 ports only.*

Hi, looking at /var/log/syslog or executing `dmesg | tail` yields the same warning on the constant reset of *USB device 008*, which apparently is a parallel port.

```
$ dmesg | tail
[13820.044078] usb 2-3.1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[13823.116151] usb 2-3.1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[13825.419253] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=727 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40729 DPT=9058 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[13825.419268] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=727 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40729 DPT=9058 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[13825.932046] usb 2-3.1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[13828.236068] usb 2-3.1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[13829.566026] [UFW ALLOW] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.36 DST=76.74.178.246 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=14119 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41592 DPT=8080 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[13831.052112] usb 2-3.1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[13834.124069] usb 2-3.1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[13836.940083] usb 2-3.1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci

$ lsusb | grep "Device 008"
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 067b:2305 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2305 Parallel Port
```

***EDIT:***
From the Prolific Tech's [website](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=6&pcid=41):

> The PL2305 integrated circuit provides a bi-directional bridge between
>   the Universal Serial Bus (USB) system and IEEE-1284 parallel port
>   printers.

I am not sure whether this is in any way the symptom of a USB port failing or whether it is rather a hardware problem of the USB to parallel port converter cable itself.

Can somebody help with a solution if there is one ? Tx.

Comment: That seems  is a USB - parallel port adapted, right?  Have you tried it in another machine or other OS? I expect a hardware problem. Go to BIOS and Disable USB 2.0, leave only USB 1.1 active. (If you have that option, this is just test, I know it is not convenient for daily work )

Comment: @Sneetsher: Thanks ! I actually thought nobody had seen this and I was ready to ask another question. I will try disabling USB 2.0 in BIOS (if I can), and will report on that. -- see my EDIT at the end of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad hardware or outdated hardware EEPROM's firmware is the answer.

I had noticed that printing over USB cable stopped working in October 2015. It was not a screaming issue since I had configured my network so network printing was possible from any network device.

It turns out my Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2305 Parallel to USB port bridging cable I used for an HP LJ4 Plus printer is equipped with a single chip that does not coexist well with something (kernel side ?) on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 Desktop OS. *[3.16.0-50-generic #67~14.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64]*

Disconnecting the cable suppresses the message completely.

Manufacturer says reconfiguring the EEPROM is possible. I will be investigating... but this falls outside the scope of the question or AU for that matter.

Comment: @Sneetsher: update above.